# Shapeless define lens for base trait

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have the next code

```
trait A { val id: Int } 
case class B(id: Int) extends A 
case class C(id: Int, name: String) extends A
```

i want to define common lens for all class hierarchy:

```
import shapeless._
import lens._ 
val idLens = lens[A] >> 'id
```

But i get error: `could not find implicit value for parameter mkLens: shapeless.MkFieldLens[A,Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("id")]]`

Is it possible to define lens for all children of `trait A`?

Comment: You have to provide an implicit MkFieldLens[A, K]. The problem is I don't know how to specify K (Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("id")]). Anyone solved this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shapeless doesn't provide an implicit conversion from `A` to `Record`. You could define `LabelledGeneric[A]` to provide the corresponding record type conversion:

```scala
import shapeless._
import lens._
import record._
import syntax.singleton._

trait A { val id: Int }
case class B(id: Int) extends A
case class C(id: Int, name: String) extends A

implicit val lgenA = new LabelledGeneric[A] {
  type Repr = Record.`'id -> Int`.T
  def to(a: A) : Repr = ('id ->> a.id) :: HNil
  def from(r: Repr): A = new A { val id = r('id) }
}

val idLens = lens[A] >> 'id

val b = B(7)
println(idLens.get(b)) // 7
```

Comment: @devkat  Thanks for the useful answer. I follow you code, and try to change the `id` value by `set` function as below: `println(idLens.set(b)(8))` , which is expecting to get a new instance of `B` back. However, it doesn't. It show some strange characters like `Test2$$anon$1$$anon$2@6276ae34`. Would please help to work out this?  Thanks in advance.